# How to remove exact match from string?

Tags: php

How i can replace/remove exact match word from string, an example string

```
$string = 'Hello world, command data test com';
```

How to remove com ( exact match from the string ) but to don't remove the com from command to

Comment: str_replace is removing com from command to, this not helping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [**preg_replace**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Basically **`preg_replace()`** searches the subject for pattern matches and replaces them with the replacement.

```
<?php
   $string = 'Hello world, command data test com';
   $string = preg_replace('/\bcom\b/', '', $string);
   echo $string;
?>
```

**Explanation:** Above example pattern is explained below

**\b:**  Match a word boundary. 
**com:** Text to match.

For more Special Character Definitions check **[this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#89364)**

Comment: Thank you! this is what i was need!

Comment: @Smartpal i don't think so, str_replace() replace command to mand

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde Yeah that's.... Sorry i forgot com in command. Up Voted

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde done i was needed to wait 4 min more to accept it

Answer (score 3):

Short version:

```
join(' ',array_diff(explode(' ', $string), ['com']));
```

Explanation:

- `explode(' ', $string)` splits your string into an array of words
- `array_diff($words, ['com'])` removes the elements on the second array from the first array. So in case the array of `$words` contains the word `com`, it will be removed
- `join(' ', $words)` concats all the strings in the `$words` array, dividing each word from each other with a space.

Full snippet:

```php
<?php
$string = 'Hello world, command data test com';
$words = explode(' ', $string);
$words = array_diff($words, ['com']);
$string = join(' ', $words);
```

Comment: even though my answer has more upvotes, but this one is my favourite! just add explanation so more people understand. Thanks!

Comment: I honestly think your one is better! Ahahah I will add some better explaination

Answer (score 1):

Another version....
If your input string alway in this order You can do it with `rtrim`

Snippet

```
$string = 'Hello world, command data test com';
$string = rtrim($string, ' com');
echo $string;
```

Output

```
Hello world, command data test
```

Live [demo](https://3v4l.org/gDCT7)

Docs
[rtrim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)